# Any way to excute code before main() or when load dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

Any way to execute code when dart file load?

I try top-level final variable, but it is execute when reach the variable

I am doing: write a simple Dependency Inject function without code generation

in di.dart file:

```dart
// top-level variable
final reg = MailRepo.register();

// or 
doReg() {
  MailRepo.register();
  MailDataSource.register();
}
```

so I can use provide<MailRepo>() in where I need MailRepo instance

And It`s not work
So I want to Know if dart provide the mechanism like CommonLisp: execute code when load file

Comment: what is your exact requirement?

Comment: I write code depend on initialize, and I don want main() method import and write initialize trigger code
what I do is write a simple Dependency Inject function

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This sounds like an XY problem for now.

Comment: I am writing a simple Dependency Inject function without code generation

Comment: No, it's not possible.  Global variables are initialized lazily.

Comment: Are there some language mechanism provide what I need? thanks

Comment: Again: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do some of my initializations *inside* main. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
var reg;

void main() {
  reg = MailRepo.register();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Or, if you absolutely need `reg` to be final, you can declare it as `late final dynamic reg;`. I'm using `dynamic` here but you'll most likely want to use the actual type of `reg`. Doing this still means that `reg` can only be assigned to once, though attempting to assign more than once won't throw errors until runtime.

Comment: thanks, but it not what I want